# Get Auth Component User ID From Middleware in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am attempting to create a 2FA Middleware with CakePHP 3. I have created the middleware basics just fine, however, I do not know how to get the user id of the current user in the middleware, typically I get the id like so...

```
$this->Auth->user('id');
```

Is there anyway to load the AuthComponent in the Middleware?

If not, how can I go about getting the current user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You can use request session handler to grab current user id

```
$this->request->session()->read( 'Auth.User.id' )
```

Comment: Bad idea because it will break when the key changes or a stateless authentication is used...

Answer (score 1):

Use the official authentication plugin which replaces the AuthComponents authentication part: https://github.com/cakephp/authentication This will oficially replace the component approach in the next release.

It features also a middleware, just make sure it's in the pipe before yours and you can use `$request->getParam('identity')`.